# Xamarin Forms 5: Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route) is navigating BACKWARDS from a page... and I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm hoping someone can help me out.  I'm developing a Xamarin Forms 5 app using Shell.  The app is 90% done, and has been working perfectly.

I've now run into an issue with a specific view.  On a view, I'm calling Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route), and the app is not navigating to the route specified, It's going BACKWARDS (Popping).

I'm 100% certain that all routes are registered properly, and that I'm specifying the correct route when navigating.

Has anyone ever seen this behavior?  I'm completely stumped.

This is the navation service functions being used:

```
public async Task PopAsync()
    {
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
    
    public async Task GoBackAsync()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }

    public async Task ReplaceCurrent<TViewModel>(string parameters = null) where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        await GoToAsync<TViewModel>(@"../", parameters);
    }

    public async Task PushAsync<TViewModel>(string parameters = null) where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        await GoToAsync<TViewModel>("", parameters);
    }

    private async Task GoToAsync<TViewModel>(string routePrefix, string parameters) where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        var route = routePrefix + typeof(TViewModel).Name;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameters))
        {
            route += $"?{parameters}";
        }
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
    }
```

the route value being passed is "DeviceInspectionEditViewModel".

The routes are registered as follows:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(WorkOrderViewModel), typeof(WorkOrderView));
  
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(InspectionListViewModel), typeof(InspectionListView));

Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(DeviceInspectionViewModel), typeof(DeviceInspectionView));

Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(DeviceInspectionEditViewModel), typeof(DeviceInspectionEditView));
```

At the time GoToAsync is called, the NavigationStack looks like this:

- [0] - {Page} null
- [1] - WorkOrderView
- [2] - InspectionListView
- [3] - DeviceInspectionView

This is the code that we're using:

```
    private async Task Edit(CertDevice dev)
    {
        var sw = Logger.LogEntry();
        await _navigationService.PushAsync<DeviceInspectionEditViewModel>();
        Logger.LogExit(sw);

    }
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

I'm seeing **"The user pressed the hardware back button"** in the debug logs.

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: You need to show code for people to help you. What is it that you're doing?

Comment: Show everything that affects the situation. The xaml with the shell contents; this defines implicit routes. Any explicit route declarations. The sequence of gotos you did before this one, if any. And of course the goto that is not working as expected.

Comment: Investigate from the idea that your route contains incorrect number of "/" in it, remove them all. My bet is you have some "//" - The route will be searched upwards from the current position. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation

Comment: A subclass was capturing "OnNavigating" and handling back button pressed ->  this has been found and resolved.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass of the view was attempting to deal with hardware back button presses by capturing OnNavigating.   This was a user error.